# Not able to invoke-Command with Parameters on Command

Tags: powershell

I currently don't get over this problem since a couple of hours, as I searched everywhere for a solution. I might don't understand the topic yet that nothing works for me.

I created with powershell a command which has to be executed on a remote computer. As for the sake of the demo, i was testing it locally first without success. This is the code and the error:

```
#Defining Date
$DateYesterday =  (Get-Date).adddays(-1)
$dateyesterdayformat = Get-Date $dateyesterday -UFormat %Y/%m/%d
$DateToday = (Get-Date -UFormat %Y/%m/%d)

#creating command
$command1 = &("C:\Program Files (x86)\CLITOOL\tool.exe display statistics " +  $dateyesterdayformat + " " + $DateToday + " *")
```

The Final String looks as follow and correct:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CLITOOL\tool.exe display statistics 2016/08/15 2016/08/16 *
```

While trying to execute this command on local server:

```
&$command1
```

I get this error:

```
The term 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CLITOOL\tool.exe display statistics 2016/08/15 2016/08/16 *' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,     function, script fil
e, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was includ
ed, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:20
+ $command1 = & <<<< ("C:\Program Files (x86)\CLITOOL\tool.exe display statistics " +  $dateyesterdayformat + " " + $DateToday + " *")
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...15     2016/08/16
    *:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I definitly see the problem but I have no clue how to resolve it. How can I create a command, where I can pass those Dates & strings as an argument and let them be called?

Thank you in advance!

Maesi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to separate the .exe and the arguments as following:

```
#creating command
$command1 = & "C:\Program Files (x86)\CLITOOL\tool.exe" "display statistics $dateyesterdayformat $DateToday *"
```

This way PowerShell executes tool.exe and passes the arguments correct.

Comment: Hey,

I get the following error while using your code:

    file userstatistics $dateyesterdayformat $DateToday * : Unexpected token 'file userstatistics $dateyesterdayformat $DateToday *' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (file userstatis...at $DateToday *:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Hey maes, sorry I miscopied your code, you have to remove the parantheses. I edited my answer

Comment: Perfect! Your command has only needed the following corrections to work properly:
I deleted the quotes on "display statistics $dateyesterdayformat $DateToday *"

Now it works! Thank you very much!